# How to bind a Map object containing Pojos to a yaml file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud-config

In a spring-boot/ spring-cloud application, I would like to bind a Map object to my application.yml but I've got a "Elements ... where lef unbound error".

In my class called Ebox, I would like to bind a map called infosTenants, indentified by a string and containing values of type InfosTenant.

Below my application.yml (without the getters / setters of each classes or subclasses)

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class ApplicationProperties {

    private Ebox ebox = new Ebox();

    public ApplicationProperties() {
    }

    // getters/setters ...

    public static class Ebox {
        private String authUrl;
        private Map<String, InfosTenant> infosTenants = new HashMap<>();

        public Ebox() {
        }

        public class InfosTenant{

            private String clientId="";
            private String clientSecret="";

            public InfosTenant() {
            }
            // getters/setters ...

        }
    }
}
```

In my application.yml, I defined one tenant in my tenants map, indentified by the key tenant1.

```
application:
    ebox:
        auth-url: https://oauth-server/api/oauth/token
        infos-tenants:
            tenant1:
                client-id: myclient
                client-secret: secret
```

But all values under infos-tenants were left unbound.
Does somebody have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have getter and setter for infosTenants?

Comment: Yes I have gérées and setters for infosTenanrs

Comment: Well `clientId` and `client-id` are different names. Use `clientId` in the YAML instead or somehow tell Spring to map the name correctly (I am not familiar with Spring YAML handling).

Comment: @flyx Spring maps automatically camelCase variables to yml. Upper-case letters are converted to lower-case letters prefixed by -

Answer (score 1):

I found my error, inner classes should be static, I forgot the static before class InfosTenant.

```
public static class InfosTenant{

        private String clientId="";
        private String clientSecret="";

        public InfosTenant() {
        }
        // getters/setters ...

    }
```